How to prevent the application from uninstalling?
Their is one parental control application already have this feature which means there controlling the Uninstallation of application like if i turn off the prevent application removal option in web, i can able to remove application, if it turn on i cannot able remove it, this what the output excepted, i have noticed that they are asking for device admin access permission for doing this functionality,
i have already tired using setUninstallBlocked method in devicePolicyManager but not working am i missing something ?
devicePolicyManager.setUninstallBlocked(componentName,this.packageName, true)
we except the same output like this app
please share our thoughts and your ideas , thanks in advance
Note : the application which i mentioned is already on playstore

You would like to read https://developer.android.com/work/device-admin

@RickyMo thanks or your comment ,do you have any other ideas on it bro
